# jQuery Fancybox 2.0.5 syntax error

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I'm trying to implement Fancybox v2.0.5 into my page. Before this, i used 1.3.4 without a problem.

The problem is, when .fancybox() has been called on an element, i get this error **whenever i click anywhere on the page**:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: )
```

I've been able to make out that it has something to do with the fact that i'm wrapping certain elements in anchors, calling it like this:

```
var $a = $("<img/>", {src:"path_to_img", alt:"YT afbeelding"})
                .wrap('<a href="#yt_editor" class="yt_vid" rel="'+video_id+'" />')
                .parent()
                .fancybox();
```

Anyone have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: I don't think that code there would cause such an error.

Comment: And yet it does: when i remove the .fancybox() part, there is no error.

Comment: So you've put that **exact** code on a page and it results in a syntax error?  Again, there's no syntax error, and the inclusion of that function call cannot cause one. *edit* - it's possible that it's something being done inside the plugin, like building a selector or something.

Comment: Can you post a link to the page? Or reproduce the error on jsfiddle.net?

Comment: How does video_id look like? I think the error is inside there..

Comment: Thank you for the fast responses everyone! I've created a (admitted, messy) JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NxLb3/

Comment: The video_id is just a youtube video ID by the way, so no braces or anything in there. And, indeed, Pointy, this is the exact code...

Comment: For the record: I have been able to call it on elements that aren't wrapped. It works without a problem in that case...

Answer (score 0):

Personally I'd call this a bug in the plugin. The problem lies in the way you're getting setting up the initialization call.  I think this should work:

```
$('.yt_img').wrap("<a href='#' class='yt_img_wrapper'/>");
$('.yt_img_wrapper').fancybox();
```

The problem is that the plugin expects to be able to use the "selector" internal jQuery value as a way to get to the element(s) on which the plugin was called, and (in my opinion) that's just a poor design decision. The selector, in your case, is ".yt_img.parent()", which is *not* a valid selector; that's what's triggering the syntax error exception.

*edit* — it's already logged as [issue #173](https://github.com/fancyapps/fancyBox/issues/173) in the GitHub bug list for Fancybox.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! I'll try to work around it and post back with the solution :-)

Comment: I think just about any code that "corrupts" the "selector" value will cause it to break.

Comment: Eventually I just rolled back to v1.3.4. I kept having issues. I may try again in some time, hopefully this issue will be resolved soon. Thanks again!